# How to Debug Weka?

Tags: debugging, weka

I am trying to implement a new filter for Weka. I would like to know, what should i do to be able to debug weka, so that I can see what's wrong with my code, since when I try to run the filter in weka I am getting exceptions. Currently I am using

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ...);
```

to print the values of variables, to try and find the problem, however I am wasting a lot of time generating jar files, coping them to the correct location, restarting weka etc... etc...

thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with using any of the usual Java debuggers? You can run Weka from Eclipse, or you can launch it with the usual debugger attach arguments and then attach to it from Eclipse.

Comment: Yeah thx, now I managed to debug it from eclipse. When i posted the question I was struggling to debug Weka from netbeans.